# What is this wire to board connector called?

Tags: connector

I'm looking for the correct terminology of the connector in the pictures below, which, as far as I understand, serves to connect unstriped wires pretty easily to some form of socket. I encountered it in a washing machine. I tried googling and going through a distributor's online catalog, but I'm not getting far without the correct jargon.

The first two pictures show the connector opened up. The metal pieces serve as both connection pin for the socket and to pierce trough the protective layer of the wires which have to be pushed trough the top holes. I suspect that first the wires are pushed trough the holes, then the metal pins are placed, and finally the whole is closed.

The last two pictures show the connector when assembled.

Edit:
To further clarify the use of the connector. It is used on the thermostat / thermistor of the the dryer in the machine.

[image: Top - partly assembled]
[image: Assembling the connector]
[image: Bottom of completed connector, side inserted into socket]
[image: Side view of completed connector]

Comment: IDC crimp plug-2p miniature plug // jack pair with bifurcated  10A contacts and interlocking jack Wire-to-Board pairs would be the generic descriptors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the exact name after a long search. The exact terminology is a **RAST 2.5** plug / wire housing (e.g. [here from molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=rast_25_connector_system&channel=products&pageTitle=Introduction)). "2.5" stands for 2.5 mm pitch (there is a 5 mm variant). This is indeed an IDC connector as Huisman suggested, but that didn't narrow the vast assortment of connectors enough to give a result. Especially different to other IDC connectors is the form of the pins. It are no simple metal bars, but a kind of clamps. Note also the ribs on one side of the connector.

I eventually discovered the exact naming by googling on the device it was used, a washing machine dryer thermostat. After noticing that many such sensors had this kind of connector, I found through the datasheet of a similar temperature probe assembly the specification of the connector type: RAST 2.5.

For people wondering wherefore this connector servers. According to  [this press release from Lumberg](https://www.lumberg.com/en/news/maximum-retaining-force-over-13-n-for-rast-2-5-connectors) (another connector manufacturer), the RAST connector has "a higher mechanical retention (...) without taking up additional casing space, made possible by the reinforced locking toes inside the reliable geometry of the casing". This makes sense given the application. It was mounted on the tumbler/drum of the washing machine, which of course exposes the connector to considerable & prolonged vibrations. (Unfortunately in my machine, not the connector, but the wire attached to it failed due to fatigue...)

Answer (score 1):

The technology is called **Insulation Displacing Connector Technology**

An **insulation-displacement contact (IDC)**, also known as **insulation-piercing contact (IPC)**, is an electrical connector designed to be connected to the conductor(s) of an insulated cable by a connection process which forces a selectively sharpened blade or blades through the insulation, bypassing the need to strip the conductors of insulation before connecting.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulation-displacement_connector

See also: [Molex about IDC](https://www.molex.com/molex/common/staticLoader.jsp?fileName=/tnotes/idtbm.html&channel=Tech+Library&chanName=&channelId=-30&programId=160&progLink=Insulation+Displacing+Technology&chanLink=&pageTitle=Insulation+Displacing+Technology)

To further narrow down, measure the pitch, estimate AWG (it may be printed on the red cables), try looking for markings on the connector (some markings are molded with the connector having the same material/colour: changing the incidence of light may make it more clear)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **stackable edge connectors**.